# numbering partitions based on changing dimensions

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I'm having some trouble creating the right partitions within my data. Here's an example of what my data looks like, complete with desired output:

```
customer   contract   type1   type2   partition
100        1          A       A       1
100        2          A       A       1
100        3          A       B       2
100        4          A       B       2
100        5          A       B       2
100        6          A       A       3
100        7          A       A       3
100        8          C       A       4
100        9          C       A       4
```

The variable I'm trying to construct is the last one, called partition. The problem I have now, is that when using `dense_rank`, contracts 1 and 2 are grouped together with contracts 6 and 7:

```
select
  t1.*
, dense_rank() over (order by customer, type1, type2) as partition
from table1 t1
```

What can I use to generate the desired output (on a fairly large dataset)?

Comment: try with `dense_rank() over (partition by customer,contract,type1,type2 order by customer, type1, type2) as partition`

Comment: @vkp that assigns the number 1 to each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want adjacent groups of rows, where "adjacent" is based on `contract`.

You can do this using a difference of `row_number()` values.  This difference is constant, when values are adjacent.  The result provide an additional grouping column that provides the information you need:

```
select t1.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by customer, type1, type2, grp) as partition
from (select t1.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by customer order by contract) -
              row_number() over (partition by customer, type1, type2 order by contract)
             ) as grp
      from table1 t1
     ) t1;
```

Comment: The described method here is referred to as the [Tabibitosan](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tabibitosan) method. [Boneist](http://www.orchestrapit.co.uk/?tag=tabibitosan), [Rob Van Wijk](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html), and [Aketi Jyuuzou](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1007478?tstart=0) all present good articles on the method

Comment: @Jyuuzou . . . I'm pretty sure I was using something similar back in my Thinking Machines days, 25 years ago, before analytics functions were part of any database.  These are tricks for taking advantage of parallel scan operations.